# Azure KeyVault Configuration Provider reload values on change

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-keyvault

I'm using Azure Key Vault Configuration Provider to read some secrets at app startup. The secrets however keep rotating throughout the day and I want to be able to reload the new values when this rotation happens.

What I'm talking about is similar to the `reloadOnChange` api

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", reloadOnChange: true);
})
```

Is this possible at all?

This is a webapi project so in practice, I could get away with manually reloading the values for every HttpRequest if that's better/more feasibe.

Comment: For the moment, I would get the secret everytime you need it from kv. There is a new `Azure App Config` feature (in preview). It is promising and will do what you're after: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview

Comment: You could also create an endpoint to reload the configuration: `IConfigurationRoot.Reload()` and invoke it anytime you update secrets in KV.

Comment: @Thomas The Azure App Config service is not the same thing as KV, it isn't for secret storage.

Comment: @juunas thanks for your comment, I misread this line from the documentation: App Configuration complements Azure Key Vault, which is used to store application secrets. I thought it would provide a unified store that can alsoget secrets from kv. anyway thanks :-)

Answer (score 17):

Using [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault (v3)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault/) you can do the following:

```
configurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions
{
    Vault = configuration["KeyVaultUrl"],
    ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
    Client = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(
       new AzureServiceTokenProvider().KeyVaultTokenCallback))
});
```

Now when you request for `IConfiguration` in your services, the KeyVault secrets will be available and refreshed based on your reload interval.

Answer (score 7):

Same thing as Bobby Koteski proposed, but with a newer [Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets) package, as [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault/) is deprecated.

`ReloadInterval` is a time to wait between attempts at polling the Azure Key Vault for changes.

```
configurationBuilder.AddAzureKeyVault(
    new SecretClient(
        new Uri(configuration["KeyVaultBaseUrl"]),
        new ManagedIdentityCredential(configuration["UserAssignedManagedIdentityClientId"])
    ),
    new AzureKeyVaultConfigurationOptions()
    {
        ReloadInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000)
    }
);
```

And [a link to a source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/f6319e4b06a8dbc8bd6913b02c0f19f6dc09c15c/sdk/extensions/Azure.Extensions.AspNetCore.Configuration.Secrets/src/AzureKeyVaultConfigurationProvider.cs) to see how it actually works :)

Comment: Thanks for including the source code. I was curious what API calls were being used.

Answer (score 3):

Secrets are cached until `IConfigurationRoot.Reload()` is called. Expired, disabled, and updated secrets in the key vault are not respected by the app until Reload is executed.

```
Configuration.Reload();
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.2#reload-secrets).

Comment: Hey, thanks. I know about this api. I was hoping to have this done automatically somehow. Or at least be able to automate it per Http request. Do you know if there's a way to do that?

Comment: When you use this and reload in browser it will automate per Http request.